the good way to implement role and permission in express rest api using prisma
I need kind of expert opinion to implement Roles and Permission in Express js. I'm planning to develop Restful Api using Express js but didn't get sufficient information or uh the flow logic to comprehend all of it things to implement Roles and Permission although there are tons of option are available for authentication and authorization.
I tried making the erd but still need more thinking way to understand this, i just want to understand.

This question is similar to: What is the best way to implement roles and permission in Express REST Api. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
